# merge sort lin linked list giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I applied merge sort algorithm to sort a linked list but when I applied it , it's     giving there is a segmentation fault(core dumped) in it.
Help me to debug it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{

    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;

    Node(int data){
        this->data = data;
        next = NULL;
    }

};

Node *takeInput(int n){

    int data;
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;

    while(n>0){

        cin >> data;
        Node *newNode = new Node(data);

        if(head == NULL){
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }else{
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }

        n--;
    }

    return head;
}


Node *merge(Node *head , Node *head2){

    Node *newhead = NULL;
    Node *newTail = NULL;

    while(head != NULL && head2 != NULL){

        int x = head->data;
        int y = head2->data;
        if(x < y){

            if(newhead == NULL){
                newhead = head ;
                newTail = head ; 
            }else{
                newTail->next = head;
                newTail = head;
            }
            head = head->next;

        }else{

            if(newhead == NULL){
                newhead = head2 ;
                newTail = head2 ; 
            }else{
                newTail->next = head2;
                newTail = head2;
            }
            head2 = head2->next;

        }

    }

    if(head == NULL){
        newTail->next = head2;
    }else{
        newTail->next = head;
    }

    return newhead;
}

Node *mergeSort(Node *head, int n){
    
    if(n == 0){
        head->next =NULL;
        return head;
    }else{

        int t = (n-1)/2;
        Node *temp = head;
        while(t>0){
        temp = temp->next;
        t--;
        }

        Node *head2 = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;

        head = mergeSort(head,n/2);
        int n2 = n - n/2 ;
        head2 = mergeSort(head2,n2);
        Node *newHead = merge(head,head2);

        return newHead;
    }
}


void print(Node *head){

    while(head != NULL){
        cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n ;
    Node *head = takeInput(n);
    Node *newHead = mergeSort(head,n);
    print(newHead);
 return 0;
}
```

I tried to debug but was not able to find out what's the fault.
I am checking for `nullptr`,`temp` as specified in one of the comment , let's see if it work.

Comment: I tried this code out, I think the problem is that you're trying to access a `nullptr`, `temp`.

Comment: There are two places where you wrote `=`but should have written `==`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes that too is one of the issues here.

Comment: corrected both '=' .

Comment: In `merge`, check for head or head2 == NULL first, not last. I"m not sure if this is the issue though. In `mergeSort` if n == 0, then just return head without checking for head->next (again, this may not be the issue).

Comment: merge is working correctly , I checked that in another program.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I debugged it.
I replaced base case of mergeSort by :

```
if(temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL){
    return temp;
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: You might want to consider [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists). It uses a small (like 32) array of lists (pointer to nodes, iterators, ...) and can be up to 30% faster that top down merge sort. The merge function would remain the same.